# Slide a div with next contents using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I used jQuery UI to slide a `div`. But the next item `.bottom-div` does not slide down/up smoothly.

I know I can do that with pure jQuery. Just for query, is this possible using jQuery UI?

https://jsfiddle.net/L4pzytkg/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `show()` and `hide()` functions, use the `slide()` function:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#showdiv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').slideDown(300);
  });

  $('#hidediv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').slideUp(300);
  });

  $('#togglediv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
}
.wrap {} .mydiv {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: orange;
}
.mydiv p {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: -15px -30px 0;
  background: yellow;
}
.below-div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="showdiv">
  Slide Down
</button>
<button type="button" id="hidediv">
  Slide Up
</button>
<button type="button" id="togglediv">
  Toggle
</button>

<div class="wrap">

  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>This is a div with long text; really extralong</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="below-div">
  This is a div below sliding div.
</div>
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/L4pzytkg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

may be like this?:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#showdiv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').show(1000);
  });

  $('#hidediv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
}
.wrap {} .mydiv {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: orange;
}
.mydiv p {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: -15px -30px 0;
  background: yellow;
}
.below-div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="showdiv">
  Slide Down
</button>
<button type="button" id="hidediv">
  Slide Up
</button>

<div class="wrap">

  <div class="mydiv">
    <p>This is a div with long text; really extralong</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="below-div">
  This is a div below sliding div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use the slide effect you could use the size effect:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#showdiv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').show('size', { origin: ['top', 'center'] }, "slow");
  });

  $('#hidediv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').hide('size', { origin: ['top', 'center'] }, "slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
}
.wrap {
}
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: orange;
}
.mydiv p {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: -15px -30px 0;
  background: yellow;
}
.below-div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="showdiv">
    Slide Down
</button>
<button type="button" id="hidediv">
    Slide Up
</button>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>This is a div with long text; really extralong</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="below-div">
    This is a div below sliding div.
</div>
```

You may also use the animate:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#showdiv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').animate( { height: "show" }, 'slow');
  });

  $('#hidediv').click(function() {
    $('.mydiv').animate( { height: "hide" }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  height: auto !important;
}
.wrap {
}
.mydiv {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: orange;
}
.mydiv p {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: -15px -30px 0;
  background: yellow;
}
.below-div {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="showdiv">
    Slide Down
</button>
<button type="button" id="hidediv">
    Slide Up
</button>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="mydiv">
        <p>This is a div with long text; really extralong</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="below-div">
    This is a div below sliding div.
</div>
```